# cpp arrays terminate called after throwing an instance of std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, arrays

I am sorry if this is really basic question I am just starting out with programming I have looked up online couldn't find anything to solve this issue.
while running my program I encountered this message "what():  std::bad_alloc" this is the first time ever for me, the program will run 2 out 5 times and for the rest I get this error in console. I don't know if something is wrong with my system or code. I really appreciate any feedback.

here is the code I am trying to write function for sorting and searching.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// function prototypes
void display(string names[], int NUM_NAMES);
void bubbleSort(string names[], int NUM_NAMES);
void selectionSort(string names[], int NUM_NAMES);
bool binarySearch(const string names[], int NUM_NAMES, string searchVal);
int main()
{
    const int NUM_NAMES = 20;
    string names[NUM_NAMES] = {"Collins, Bill", "Smith, Bart", "Allen, Jim",
                                "Griffin, Jim", "Stamey, Marty", "Rose, Geri",
                                "Taylor, Terri", "Johnson, Jill",
                                "Allison, Jeff", "Looney, Joe", "Wolfe, Bill",
                                "James, Jean", "Weaver, Jim", "Pore, Bob",
                                "Rutherford, Greg", "Javens, Renee",
                                "Harrison, Rose", "Setzer, Cathy",
                                "Pike, Gordon", "Holland, Beth" };

    // calling bubble sort function
    bubbleSort(names, NUM_NAMES);
    cout << "Displaying Bubble Sort results"<<endl;
    display(names, NUM_NAMES);
    // calling selection sort function
    selectionSort(names, NUM_NAMES);
    cout << "\n\nDisplaying Selection Sort Results"<<endl;
    display(names, NUM_NAMES);

    // searching through array
    string name;
    cout << "Enter a names to be searched in the array: ";
    getline (cin, name);
    bool found = binarySearch(names, NUM_NAMES, name);
    //(found== true)?cout << "name Exists"<<endl: cout << "Name does not Exist"<<endl;
    cout << "===================="<<endl;
    if(found)
            cout << "Name exists"<<endl;
    else
        cout << "Name does not exist"<<endl;


    return 0;
}
// display array
void display(string names[], int NUM_NAMES)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<NUM_NAMES; i++)
        cout << names[i]<<endl;;
}

// bubble search Function
void bubbleSort(string names[], int NUM_NAMES)
{
    bool swap;
    string temp;
    do{
        swap = false;
        for (int i = 0; i<NUM_NAMES; i++)
        {
            if(names[i]>names[i+1])
            {
                temp = names[i];
                names[i] = names[i+1];
                names[i+1] = temp;
                swap = true;
            }
        }
    }
    while (swap);
}
// selection Sort Function
void selectionSort(string names[], int NUM_NAMES)
{
    int start, minIndex;
    string minVal;
    for (start = 0; start<NUM_NAMES-1; start++)
    {
        minVal = names[start];
        minIndex = start;
        for (int scan= start+1; scan<NUM_NAMES; scan++)
        {
            if(names[scan] < minVal)
            {
                minVal = names[scan];
                minIndex = scan;
            }
        }
        names[minIndex] = names[start];
        names[start] = minVal;
    }
}
bool binarySearch(const string names[], int NUM_NAMES, string searchVal)
{
    bool found = false;
    int first = 0, last = NUM_NAMES-1, mid;
    while(!found && first<=last)
    {
        mid = (first+last)/2;
        if (names[mid] == searchVal)
        {
            found = true;
        }
        else if(searchVal < names[mid])
        {
            last = mid-1;
        }
        else
            first = mid+1;
    }
    return found;
}
```

Comment: You have declared the size of `names` as 20, but there are more than 20 elements. Make it more than 20(maybe 23 )

Comment: Check your `bubbleSort`. There you have `names[i+1]  = temp `. And when `i= NUM_NAMES-1` (this is possible due to the `for`-loop range is [0;NUM_NAMES)`) you will write memory after the end of array.

Comment: Thank you so much Serg, apparently I was accessing memory outside of my array boundaries. I really appreciate your contribution that helps a lot man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program is throwing an `std::bad_alloc` [exception](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/bad_alloc) at some point and, since your are not handling this exception, it halts. This is due to some flaw on memory management.

Check your bubble-sort algorithm. Specifically, the `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i<NUM_NAMES; i++)
{
    if(names[i]>names[i+1]) // Do you notice the error in this line?
    {
        temp = names[i];
        names[i] = names[i+1];
        names[i+1] = temp;
        swap = true;
    }
}
```

In the last iteration of this loop, `i` becomes `NUM_NAMES-1`, so that `names[i+1]` is equivalent to `names[NUM_NAMES]`, which is out of range! You need to simply restate the `for` loop as

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM_NAMES-1; i++)
```

and it should work fine.

Comment: Yes Mr. Ibarbele I can see my mistake now, Thanks a lot for having a look at it and addressing the error, I appreciate that.